# How to convert old liveview app to new Phoenix version?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-live-view

### Background

I am in the process of porting an old LiveView app to the newest version of Phoenix ( v1.6.5). Being new to the whole thing in general I was expecting to run `mix phx.new web_interface --live --no-ecto` and to the find a similar structure to what I had before:

```
├───assets
│   ├───css
│   ├───js
│   └───static
│       └───images
├───config
├───lib
│   ├───web_interface
│   └───web_interface_web
│       ├───channels
│       ├───live
│       ├───templates
│       │   └───layout
│       └───views
└───priv
    └───static
        └───assets
```

Instead I got:

```
├───assets
│   ├───css
│   ├───js
│   └───vendor
├───lib
│   └───web_interface
│       ├───controllers
│       ├───templates
│       │   ├───layout
│       │   └───page
│       └───views
└───priv
    ├───gettext
    │   └───en
    │       └───LC_MESSAGES
    └───static
        ├───assets
        └───images
```

### Something is missing

Paying close attention you will now see I am missing a couple of important folders, namely, `web_interface_web` and the `live` folder.

So now I am understand the impression I either missed a huge milestone upgrade or that something is wrong with my `mix phx.new` command.

### Questions

- Why are these folders missing?
- How can I port the project? What are the equivalent folders now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running on Elixir 1.13 and Phoenix 1.6.5, there should be a and `web_interface` and `web_interface_web` directories given the command you provided `mix phx.new web_interface --live --no-ecto` (I put the output of that command below). The `live` directory doesn't get created until you generate your first LiveView views with something like `mix phx.gen.live Accounts User users name:string age:integer`

This looks like an older version of Phoenix or Elixir. You may have generated the project in a different shell session that references a different version of Elixir or Phoenix. Also, What version of Phoenix does `mix.exs` say?

Check your version of Elixir with `elixir --version`

```
➜  projects$ elixir --version
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.0.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [jit] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.13.0 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 24)
```

Then check the version of the `phx` package you have installed with `mix archive`

```
➜  projects$ mix archive      
* hex-1.0.1
* phx_new-1.6.5
Archives installed at: /Users/cj1/.kiex/mix/archives/elixir-1.13.0
```

If you need to reinstall the phx package, run the ([`mix archive.install hex phx_new` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/installation.html))

```
➜  projects$ mix archive.install hex phx_new

Resolving Hex dependencies...
Dependency resolution completed:
New:
  phx_new 1.6.5
* Getting phx_new (Hex package)
All dependencies are up to date
Compiling 11 files (.ex)
Generated phx_new app
Generated archive "phx_new-1.6.5.ez" with MIX_ENV=prod
Are you sure you want to install "phx_new-1.6.5.ez"? [Yn] y
* creating /Users/cj1/.kiex/mix/archives/elixir-1.13.0/phx_new-1.6.5
```

This is what I get when I run the command you have:

```
➜  projects$ mix phx.new web_interface --live --no-ecto
* creating web_interface/config/config.exs
* creating web_interface/config/dev.exs
* creating web_interface/config/prod.exs
* creating web_interface/config/runtime.exs
* creating web_interface/config/test.exs
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface/application.ex
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface.ex
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web/views/error_helpers.ex
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web/views/error_view.ex
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web/endpoint.ex
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web/router.ex
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web/telemetry.ex
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web.ex
* creating web_interface/mix.exs
* creating web_interface/README.md
* creating web_interface/.formatter.exs
* creating web_interface/.gitignore
* creating web_interface/test/support/channel_case.ex
* creating web_interface/test/support/conn_case.ex
* creating web_interface/test/test_helper.exs
* creating web_interface/test/web_interface_web/views/error_view_test.exs
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web/controllers/page_controller.ex
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web/views/page_view.ex
* creating web_interface/test/web_interface_web/controllers/page_controller_test.exs
* creating web_interface/test/web_interface_web/views/page_view_test.exs
* creating web_interface/assets/vendor/topbar.js
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web/templates/layout/root.html.heex
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web/templates/layout/app.html.heex
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web/templates/layout/live.html.heex
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web/views/layout_view.ex
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web/templates/page/index.html.heex
* creating web_interface/test/web_interface_web/views/layout_view_test.exs
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface/mailer.ex
* creating web_interface/lib/web_interface_web/gettext.ex
* creating web_interface/priv/gettext/en/LC_MESSAGES/errors.po
* creating web_interface/priv/gettext/errors.pot
* creating web_interface/assets/css/phoenix.css
* creating web_interface/assets/css/app.css
* creating web_interface/assets/js/app.js
* creating web_interface/priv/static/robots.txt
* creating web_interface/priv/static/images/phoenix.png
* creating web_interface/priv/static/favicon.ico

Fetch and install dependencies? [Yn] y
* running mix deps.get
* running mix deps.compile

We are almost there! The following steps are missing:

    $ cd web_interface

Start your Phoenix app with:

    $ mix phx.server

You can also run your app inside IEx (Interactive Elixir) as:

    $ iex -S mix phx.server
```